# Laravel VerifyCsrfToken exclude not working

Tags: laravel, api, csrf

I'm having an issue excluding /api route from verifying token.

I'm trying to exclude all routes but not working

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        //
        '*',
    ];
}
```

Comment: If you really want to disable csrf for all route, then delete this line `\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,` from `app\Http\Kernel.php` on `$middlewareGroups` property

Comment: yes I've done this but not working

I'm trying to send form data from javascript but got this error

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8088/api/example. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Comment: CORS is not related to CSRF. If you are using Laravel 8, change value of 'allowed_origins' to `'allowed_origins' => ['*'],` at config/cors.php

Comment: yes that is there but still not working

Comment: @RanickPatra can you update your question wth config/cors.php code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I suggest is, create a middleware and use it in your routes:

Create `app/Http/Middleware/Cors.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, \Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
    
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
    
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Modify `app/Http/Kernel.php`

```
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        ...
        'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
    ];
```

Finally, use it in your route file eg: `routes/web.php`

```
Route::middleware(['cors'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'YourController@yourFunction');
});
```